# Passing parameter to method returning Func

Tags: c#, delegates

I have the following static class

```
public static partial class ClassX
    {
        private static readonly Expression<Func<Customer, CustomerDetail>> _exp = DoX();
        private static readonly Func<Customer, CustomerDetail> _comp = DoX().Compile();

        static ClassX() { }

        public static IQueryable<CustomerDetail> ConvertDetail(this IQueryable<Customer> query)
        {
            query.Select(_exp);
        }

        public static CODEDistrictDTO ConvertDetail(this Customer customer)
        {
            return _comp(customer);
        }

        private static Expression<Func<CODEDistrictEntity, CODEDistrictDTO>> DoX()
        {

        }
    }
```

What I need to do is passing a parameter to "DoX" method through the method "ConvertDetail", so the "DoX" method build the logic base on the received parameter

```
public static partial class ClassX
    {
        private static readonly Expression<Func<Customer, CustomerDetail>> _exp = DoX(); //problem
        private static readonly Func<Customer, CustomerDetail> _comp = DoX().Compile();  //problem

        static ClassX() { }

        public static IQueryable<CustomerDetail> ConvertDetail(this IQueryable<Customer> query, List<int> mlist)
        {
            query.Select(_exp(mlist));
        }

        public static CODEDistrictDTO ConvertDetail(this Customer customer, List<int> mlist)
        {
            return _comp(customer,mlist);
        }

        private static Expression<Func<CODEDistrictEntity, CODEDistrictDTO>> DoX(List<int> mlist)
        {

        }
    }
```

The problem in the static readonly fields!!!

Comment: Are you looking for fully fledged dynamic/runtime compilation? Or would it be sufficient to have some code you wrote yourself, that is picked out via a switch/case or a `Dictionary<string, Action>`?

Comment: yes, returning dynamic/runtime compilation

Answer (score 0):

Take another look at the syntax for how a `Func<>` is defined:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-2

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-3

```
public delegate TResult Func<in T,out TResult>(T arg);
public delegate TResult Func<in T1,in T2,out TResult>(T1 arg1, T2 arg2);
```

The definition you have applied at the top for `Func<Customer, CustomerDetail>` then means that you are providing a delegate function that takes in one parameter of type `Customer` and returns a result of type `CustomerDetail`. This following block calls the delegate function `_comp` with the `customer` value as that parameter.

```
public static CODEDistrictDTO ConvertDetail(this Customer customer)
{
   return _comp(customer); // <- Calls our delegate Func<Customer,CustomerDetail> with a Customer param, returns a CustomerDetail
}
```

In your updated code, you suddenly start trying to pass two parameters to that delegate function with `_comp(customer,mlist)`, but it is only defined as having one. To change the delegate to expect two parameters, with the second being of type `List<int>`, then you would need to update that to `private static readonly Func<Customer, List<int>, CustomerDetail> _comp = ...`

Keep in mind this is only going to help you if your `DoX.Compile()` method will actually accept this signature - updating the Func does not mean your provided delegate will suddenly know what to do with the extra parameter if it doesn't already expect it.

Comment: ` private static readonly Func<List<int>,Expression<Func<Customer, CustomerDetail>>> _exp = DoX(); // works
        private static readonly Func<Customer, CustomerDetail> _comp = DoX().Compile();  //How to call compile() ? `

Comment: I have added some clarification. The `Func<T, TResult>` is just a delegate, or a way of saying "hey, give me a method that will take in a parameter of this type and return a result of this type". You can update the Func, but you'll need to ensure your `DoX.Compile()` knows what to do with it.